# Difference between debug and release mode DLL

Tags: vb.net, debugging, dll

I have a problem with third-party dll in Visual basic 2008. This dll makes a connection to external hardware device (an external POS terminal), which needs to be closed when the application ends. When the application is in debug mode, it's working fine, but in release mode after calling the closing method a dialog box is appearing with error code 0.
The dialog box is appearing after calling of method ExitLibProc() from the code below. ExitLibProc is imported from the dll.

```
Public Sub Close()
    EasyFiskal.ExitLibProc()
End Sub
```

My question is: Does Visual Basic post debug/release mode to non-.Net dll-s? If doesn't, why is this difference between release and debug modes?

Comment: What kind of DLL is it? Native, COM, .NET?